# invalid password while importing wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I deleted monero wallets files by mistakenly. Now i recovered it using undelete software(for linux). But when i try to import it in gui wallet and enter my password , it says 'invalid password'. Is there any way to check that keys file is corrupted or not ? If that keys file is corrupted, Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Did you by any chance back-up the key files before deleting the wallet files from your computer?

Comment: no, there is no chance.